# JS НЕ могу найти ошибку

Tags: javascript

Дан массив с элементами `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`. С помощью цикла `for` создайте строку `-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-`.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
s = '-';
s1 = ""
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   s1 += string(arr[i]);
   s += s1;
}
alert(s+'-');
```

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: устраните ошибки в консоли для начала. потом s1 стартовым значением сделайте `-`

Comment: String, а не string. С большой буквы

Comment: `let res = "-"; for (let val of arr) res += val + "-";`

Comment: `const res = '-' + arr.join('-') + '-'`

Comment: @Владимир где тут цикл `for`?

Comment: @Алексей версию с for я отметил как ответ, вариант c join как пример)